# facebook api php: how to use actions link for under the wall post? error

Tags: php, facebook, post, action

I'm trying to make my app post on the user's wall. Under the post is a link to the app page on fb, i want a link to the app itself, so i'm trying actions, name and link. but for some reason there is only 'A' and the url becomes my url with "/A" added, so it doesn't work anymore:(

Can someone help me please? Probably I made a stupid mistake so won't take much of you time. Thanks!

Part of my code:

```
$action = array('name' => $aname, 'link' => $alink);
$actions = json_encode($action);


  $apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$userid/feed";
  $parameters = "?access_token=" . $access . "&message=" . 
    $mymessage . "&actions=" . $action . "&method=post";
  $myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;

  $result = file_get_contents($myurl);
```

So it does work, only there is a problem with the actions part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
$mymessage . "&actions=" . $action . "&method=post";
```

to:

```
$mymessage . "&actions=" . urlencode($actions) . "&method=post";
```

Comment: That does the trick! Thanks a lot. Do you by any chance know if and how it is possible to change the link under the post which sends you to the page of the app into a link to the app itself?

Comment: @nikhil ahhh nope I don't think that could be changed.

Comment: please look at the part under the ____________________

Comment: never mind, there is a problem with my conditions, because if i go to a page that doesn't exist and then go back, suddenly there is a session, so i should be able to work it out by myself